# How to generate dynamic name for a <td> and pass the name of it to server

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following code :

```
                        {% for assessments in list_assessments%}
<form action="/test/" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
                        <tr>
                        <td>{{assessments.assessment_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.assessment_begin_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.assessment_end_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.is_active}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.is_complete}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.created_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.updated_at}}<br></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Assessment" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                        </form>
```

All the data here are dynamically coming.
In this following code, i need to assign an name to assessments.name dynamically, something like

```
<td name="dynamic_name">{{assessment.name}}</td>.
```

And on clicking the button "Edit Assessment", i want the dynamic_name to be passed and received my the view.

The idea is each assessment has its own set of parameters. I want to display only the parameters related to the name. So if i could pass the value i would be able to do it.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Seems this piece of code is missing {% for }. Please provide proper code.

Comment: You can't pass a name from some random HTML element without using Javascript. Why don't you make it a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ending `**</form>**` tag should be before **for** loop.

```
{% for assessments in list_assessments%}
                      <form action="/test/" method="post" name="form-{{ assessments.counter }}">{%csrf_token%}
                        <tr>
                        <td>{{assessments.assessment_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.assessment_begin_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.assessment_end_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.is_active}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.is_complete}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.created_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{assessments.updated_at}}<br></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Assessment" /></td>
                        </tr>
                      </form>
{%endfor%}
```

Now, You can get specific block values by **form name** ( see above code ) in javascript as well as in python.

**In Javascript,**

```
form = document.getElementByTagName("form")
elems = form.children("td")
```

**elems** will give you all **td** elements.

Comment: It creates multiple forms. So when you submit specific form, then you will get specific block of values in Django Views using request.POST.get

Comment: Then there is only one small issue i.e You need to put </form> element before {%endfor%} instead of after {%endfor%} .

Comment: I dont have a javascript...   there is just the view and on click i dont want the whole thing to be passed..
i just want the assessment.name to be passed..
just like in login we pass the username and password..

Comment: then use <input type="hidden" name="assessment_name" value="{{assessments.name}}"/>  inside form element. and you will get 

assessment_name = request.POST.get("assessment_name")